# How to preload JSON link?

Tags: javascript, json, preload

I've got a function that needs to call a link (JSON format), the fact is that I would like to be able to preload this link to smooth and reduce the operation time when calling the function.

```js
onSelectionChanged: function (selectedItems) {
    selectedItems.selectedRowsData.forEach(function(data) {
        if(data) {
            colorMe(data.target)     
        }
    });
}

function colorMe(item){
    globalItem = item;
    request('http://blablabla/?format=json',findMaterial);
};  

function findMaterial(data){        
    jq310.each(data, function(table) {
        if (data[table].identifier == globalItem){
            globalData = data[table]
            request('http://another-blablabla/?format=json',findMatchArea);

        };
    });
};

function findMatchArea(areas){                      
    jq310.each(areas, function(area) {

        blablabla
```

The request function that I built just look if the link as been already called, so it's reloading it if true. And also send data from the link to the called function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'r looking to load a static json file you should concider loading it on the top of your file. To do so you should store the datas in a global variable like that :

```
let datas;

request('http://blablabla/?format=json', (data) => {
  datas = data
});

onSelectionChanged: function (selectedItems) {
  selectedItems.selectedRowsData.forEach(function(data) {
      if(data) {
        globalItem = data.target;
        findMaterial();
      }
  });
}

function colorMe(item){
  globalItem = item;
};  

function findMaterial(){    
  const data = datas;    
  jq310.each(data, function(table) {
      if (data[table].identifier == globalItem){
          globalData = data[table]
          request('http://another-blablabla/?format=json',findMatchArea);

      };
  });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I finally found a way to do it properly, here it is :

```js
var mylink = 'https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript';

function preloadURL(link){
    var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhReq.open("GET", link, false);
    xhReq.send(null);
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(xhReq.responseText);
    return jsonObject;
};

jsonObjectInv = preloadURL(mylink);
```

And I just point to my json variable to parse it (really faster)

```js
function colorMe(item){
    globalItem = item;
    findMaterial(jsonObjectInv);
};
```

Problem solved